# Installing three way switch in two gang box

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I’m trying to replace two normal, separate three way switches with Lutron Caseta Wireless system. So far I have only gotten either 1) the right switch works perfectly and the left switch does not work at all or 2) the right switch operates both lights which are supposed to be separate and the left does nothing still. I tried to follow a diagram and I ended up with result 2. [image: diagram that I followed]

This is what I have done to get result 2: [image: sorry for the bad photo]

Sorry for the bad photo, but it is the same as the diagram except the black/grey wires are all sort of combined (which I don’t think would affect the circuit). Thank you so much for any advice you might be able to provide.

EDIT: the original circuit looked like this, and just a reminder that the functions of the switches should be completely separate: [image: original switches]

Comment: How were the 2 original 3-way switches connected? Did you nut those white wires together or were they like that before (notice how I'm not assuming they're neutral...)? They way you've got it now looks like there aren't enough wires to support 2 3-way switches, but if those whites aren't neutrals and weren't nutted together ....

Comment: @brhans I will update my post with how the original circuit looked. Sorry if the photo doesn’t have enough information. The white wires were NOT originally together. Also, just a reminder that the switches should function separately entirely. Thank you!

Comment: Are the wireless switches three-way? I see only two wires on each.

Comment: I don't know what that diagram is supposed to represent but it has nothing to do with either photo or anything you describe. If that's what you tried to follow then there's no wonder that your final result doesn't work, the only mystery is how you have not tripped any breakers or set yourself on fire.

Comment: @mile65535 The wireless switches work by having a main switch like the ones pictured above, and all other switches are replaced with a wireless remote that looks like it is a normal switch. The wireless remotes simply connect to the main switch and turn it on/off. That allows them to work in a three-way manner, if that answers your question. Thanks!

Comment: @A. I. Breveleri Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your third photo clearly shows the ends of two separate "three-way" switch circuits. Where are the other ends? Where is power fed into the circuit? How are the lamps connected? - We're looking at only about one-third of the picture.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is possible and reasonable, but you're going to have to completely analyze the existing circuit first. This won't be difficult but it involves looking at all (both?) the switch boxes.

Comment: Can you post photos of what's in the boxes for the other switches on these circuits?

Comment: I think you'll find your test results are very dependent on the switch position of the other three way switches. Not that you should be throwing them randomly, this entire circuit complex requires a lot more thought.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what you had before were 2 completely separate 3-way switches.
The White wires *are not neutrals* in either of them, and this is normal!
Depending on which end of the 3-way wiring we're looking at, the Black wires may not even be Hot, and if they are, they may not be on the same breaker or even on the same phase (although if they were on different phases you'd probably know about it by now due to the tripped breakers and/or big flash/bang).

What you had on each switch: Black (common) Red & White (Travelers) - so depending on the switch position, either the Red or the White is connected to the Black.
If you look at the 3-way switches on the other end of each cable you should find the same wiring.

So, remove that nut on the white wires - they're not neutrals and do not belong together. Instead, put a nut on each one individually and forget about them.
Also remove the nut you've put on to join all of the Blacks together - they're not the same circuit.

Go to the 3-way switches at the other ends of those cables, remove the switches, nut the white wires individually and forget about them as you've just done, and nut the Red and Black on each cable to each other (not between cables).
Now go back to your wireless switches and connect each one individually to the Red and Black on each cable.

Done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I simply forgot to connect the red and black wires on the other switch. Followed your instructions for the junction and now they are all separate and it’s all working great.